# Appropriate ways to remove aluminum from the surface of glass?

Tags: solubility, equipment, cleaning, glass

I'm looking for a way to treat the surface of borosilicate glassware such that it won't contaminate solutions of puriss reagents in conditions that pure $\ce{SiO2}$ wouldn't, yet keep the bulk physical properties (and low cost) of standard borosilicate glassware.

What are appropriate ways (i.e. without etching or contaminating the glassware) to remove aluminum from the surface of borosilicate glassware to avoid it contaminating solutions?

One (inappropriate way) would be to use an $\ce{NaOH}$ solution I guess, but that would etch the glass to some extent, and thus expose more impurities in the glass.

Comment: One standard aluminum etch is 25:5:1 phosphoric:acetic:nitric which does not attack pure SiO2 or standard glassware.

Comment: Maybe salmi (dilute NH4+/NH3), aqueous ammonia, could do the trick?
See [chem.libretxts.org - on al3+ reactions with NH3](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analytical_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Analytical_Chemistry)/Qualitative_Analysis/Characteristic_Reactions_of_Select_Metal_Ions/Characteristic_Reactions_of_Aluminum_Ions_(Al%C2%B3%E2%81%BA))

Comment: @John: Are you sure phosphoric doesn't etch glassware?

Comment: @Lars: Isn't salmi NH4Cl?

Comment: From the link NH4OH is said to form an Aluminum precipitate, so it wouldn't help solubilize the Aluminum from the glass. But maybe NH4 in an HCl solution?